# huffman algorithm in python

Tags: python, huffman-code

HI!

Could anybody say how to fix the problem in the Huffman algorthm (if put together all the parts) from this Internet site:

http://www.builderau.com.au/program/python/soa/Huffman-coding-in-Python/0,2000064084,339283616,00.htm

Error:

```
 itemqueue =  [Node(a, len(list(b))) for a, b in groupby(sorted(input))]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you fix the link?

Answer (score 4):

I think you forgot to declare `input`.
It should work fine otherwise.

Comment: by the way input as a built-in name is a poor name for a variable